# How to stop Authorizing when using localhost for an ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API that uses Okta to authorize and authenticate.  The problem is that the instance of Okta I'm using blocks localhost requests with CORS.  If we assume that I can't change that, this is the approach I've taken:

```
#if !DEBUG
[Authorize]
#endif
public class ApiValuesController : ControllerBase
{
//stuff
}
```

And in startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     //...
     if (!Environment.IsDevelopment())
     {
         //add authentication
         services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
               options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
               options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               options.Authority = Configuration["Okta:Authority"];
               options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
               options.ClientId = Configuration["Okta:ClientId"];
               options.ClientSecret = "LOL No";
               options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
               options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
               options.Scope.Add("openid");
               options.Scope.Add("profile");
               options.SaveTokens = true;
               options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
               {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "groups",
                    ValidateIssuer = true
               };
           });
           services.AddAuthorization();
        }
        //...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //...
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            //enable authentication
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
        }
        //...
    }
```

But this causes a problem if I need to run my release build locally for any reason.  Surely there's a better way for me to be able to run release builds locally without breaking authorization.

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Have you tried adding CORS middleware and configuring a policy that allows localhost i.e. `services.AddCors`?

Comment: Can't you add CORS policy in Okta itself? You can allow Okta to accept certain domains by enabling those domains in CORS policy.

Comment: Ah, I thought that CORS only affected requests TO this API, not FROM this API. The file does have services.AddCors, but not for localhost